# bicubic keyframe interpolation

Tags: animation, graphics, interpolation, skeletal-animation

I am trying to implement what is presented in this very interesting tech conference about animation
http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1020583/Animation-Bootcamp-An-Indie-Approach

As a quick summary, it is about making an pose based animation system. Instead of playing animation, we play fix poses and interpolate between different poses to create the motion.

I am successfully doing linear interpolation between different pose by lerping the model space translation and slerping the model space rotation between two poses.

However, at 7:30 it is proposed to interpolate using bicubic interpolation, in order to assure position and speed continuity.

I spend some times thinking and researching about it, but I am not really sure what it means.

Could anyone provide me a bit of guidance on this question

Comment: the wikipedia page has pretty good definitions in series notation..

Comment: I read that, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation but what is not clear is on which variable the interpolation should happen: euler angle? quaternion components?

Comment: I saw this video just a few days ago, and was wondering why he stated that he used bicubic interpolation. A "bi-" variant of interpolation would only be needed in a situation where the values to be interpolated vary over a two-dimensional region (like a height map or a texture, for blending between pixels). Key frame data only vary over time.

Comment: totally agree with you. So far, I can just understand he misspoke on this specific point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/articles/article1497.html

This links describes how to perform cubic interpolation.